# How to report dividend reported on French form 2777

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-income

I live in the US, but the parent company of my employer is headquartered in France. It's a privately held corporation, and I received some stock as a bonus a few years ago.

Last year they underwent some kind of reorganization, and as a result I received a cash dividend.

I'm working on my 2022 US taxes, and I'm not sure how to report this. I didn't receive a 1099. I received a French form 2777. I can't understand anything on it, since it's written in French. I took French in high school 45 years ago, so I only speak it *un peu*.

I'm using TurboTax Deluxe to do my taxes, I have no idea what I need to enter and where. I've always been able to do my own taxes -- the most complicated thing I've ever had is a 10K from a limited partnership. Is it time to give up and go to H&R Block to deal with this?

Comment: Your regular H&R block neighborhood office will probably not cut it. Try to find someone who's specializing in french expats. There's a tax treaty involved, proper understanding of each line item and proper understanding of how they're defined in French law and how it corresponds to the IRC. Or ask Franck.

Comment: It's not going to help you lots because it's also in french and I couldn't find any translation but every french tax form comes with a notice which is sort of a manual for the form. The notice for form 2777 (year 2023) can be found [here](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/formulaires/2777-sd/2023/2777-sd_4228.pdf). If you want previous years editions, they can be found [here](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/formulaire/2777-sd/revenus-de-capitaux-mobiliers-prelevement-et-retenue-la-source).